# How to use "awk" to modify the same line many times

Tags: awk

I have a file,named score.tsv, the content is much more like:

```
1 jack 100 good
2 tom  50  notgood
....
```

and i want to modify the fourth field of the second line "notgood" to "fail"
i used

```
awk -F"\t" '{if (NR==2) $4="fail";print > "temp.tsv"}' score.tsv
```

it works.

then i realized i need to change the second field of the second line to "lily" too.
so i tried

```
awk -F"\t" '{if (NR==2) $2="lily";print > "temp1.tsv"}' temp.tsv
```

it doesn't work.

the content of temp1.tsv is

```
1 jack 100 good
2 tom  50  fail lily
.....
```

how can i change the fields in one line of a file one by one? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is, in your first command `nogood->fail`, you didn't assgin `OFS`. so that in your tmp.txt, it is NOT `<tab>` separated. so in your 2nd command, the `$2` actually didn't exist, awk will **append** `lily` to the 2nd line.

try this two lines:

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{if (NR==2) $4="fail";print > "temp.tsv"}' score.tsv
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '{if (NR==2) $2="lily";print > "temp1.tsv"}' temp.tsv
```